# Actionscript object colour change / tint

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, colors

i am new to Actionscript and I need help changing the colour of an object which is called with `add child`, i need the colour to change once the user has selected the desired colour they want from a combo box:

```
//MY CODE

if (e.target.value == "blue")

{

//need to change to this (0x0000FF)

//enter code here

}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Consider upvoting useful answers, and accept the answer that you feel best helped to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Try using the color transform object.

```
var redAmount:Number = 0;
var greenAmount:Number = 0;
var blueAmount:Number = 1;
var alphaAmount:Number = 1;
var redOffset:Number = 0;
var greenOffset:Number = 0;
var blueOffset:Number = 0;
var alphaOffset:Number = 0;
yourDisplayObject.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(redAmount, greenAmount, blueAmount, alphaAmount, redOffset, greeenOffset, blueOffset, alphaOffset);
```

The first four variables are multipliers - they will take the existing color value and adjust it as if multiplying by that number. So to reduce a color by 1/2 use 0.5. To make black set all to 0. To change nothing make all 1's.

The second four variables will increase or decrease the color amount of all pixels by that amount. So to make a color hit a specific hex value, say 0xFFCC33, you would do this:

```
yourDisplayObject.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(0, 0, 0, 1, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0x33, 0x00);
```

Here is a link to the adobe documentation if you need more help:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html

If you decide you want to change the color gradually instead of instantly take a look at TweenMax from greensock. The greensock tween classes are a widely used workhorse of actionscript programming.

To tint a display object with TweenMax the code would be:

```
TweenMax.to(yourDisplayObject, 1, {tint:0x0000FF});
```

This class applies a color transform to the object using that code, but it changes the values gradually over time

Here is a link to where you can get TweenMax.
http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest to understand (as I see it anyway) way to accomplish this:

```
if (e.target.value == "blue")
{

    var colorTransform:ColorTransform = yourObject.transform.colorTransform;  //store the current color data for the object
    colorTransform.color = 0x0000FF; //make it totally blue
    yourObject.transform.colorTransform = colorTransform; //now assign it back to the object

}
```